# Can't install VirtualBox 6.0.8 on MacOS X 10.14.5

Tags: macos, virtualbox

Installation fails every time with this message:

[image: Screenshot of VirtualBox Install Failling]

I'm sure I could revert back to 5.2 but would prefer to use the latest and greatest.

Thanks.

Comment: So, did you contact the software manufacturer first, as advised?

Comment: @Tetsujin as in Oracle? No

Comment: @Biswapriyo Negative

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116604

Basically, you need to add Oracle's developer ID. While in recovery mode enter: `spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963` in the terminal and then restart. Installing VirtualBox on updated 10.14.5 Mojave installations will once again work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Shutdown your Mac
2. Press "Power button" and immediately after that press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (when you will hear the boot chime you can release <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
3. On the next screen choose your language or English and press "Next"
4. from the top bar choose "Utilities" -> "Terminal"
5. fill in:  `spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963`   (take care about capital letters)  and press Enter
6. Restart your Mac (on the top: "An Apple -> Restart")